# Join Mongodb and search with in joined table with laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

i want to join tables in laravel using mongodb database and search parameters with in two tables. i have used with has but it is not working. i want to search parameters with in join table with like condition.

i have tried with has condition.

```
$CustomerData = Customer::orderBy('_id', 'desc');
$CustomerData = $CustomerData
->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
->with('addressData')  
    ->whereHas('addressData',       
        function($query) use ($search)  
        {          
           $query->orWhere('country', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');       
           $query->orWhere('state', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');          
         });
```

Comment: use **whereRaw()** instead of where

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ljubadr there is no error comes up. just not getting records by search.

Comment: @InzamamIdrees sir, whereRaw() is not working. please give me sample example for join table and search with that two tables. Thank you,

Comment: Then it's hard to say, because we can't see the db data... Check your logic, because your query will return only results that match: (customer firstname OR middlename matches search) AND (it must have relation `addressData` where country OR state match search). If one of them fails, you won't get any results

Comment: `->whereHas` will only load models that have relation that matches your search condition. This will not do the `mysql join`...

Comment: You could replace your `->whereHas(` with `->with(`. If you do that, for each `Customer` that matches search, it will only load `addressData` that match search.

Comment: @ljubadr oh, thank you sir. but please give me some example or reference by which i can join tables with mongodb laravel like wise codeigniter query. so it will be very grateful help for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Vishal check this sample code for searching between different tables:

**Code here:**

```
  public function SimpleSearch($term)
  {
    $match = "MATCH(authors.authors) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    $match1 = "MATCH(keywords.keywords) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    $match2 = "MATCH(research_papers.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    $match3 = "MATCH(research_papers.abstract) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    $researchpapers = DB::table('keywords')
    ->join('research_papers','keywords.researchpaper_id','=','research_papers.id')
    ->join('authors','authors.researchpaper_id','=','research_papers.id')
    ->leftjoin('favorite_models','favorite_models.researchpaper_id','=','research_papers.id')
    ->whereRaw($match1,array($term))
    ->orwhereRaw($match2,array($term))
    ->orwhereRaw($match3,array($term))
    ->orwhereRaw($match,array($term))
    ->orderbyRaw($match2."DESC",array($term))
    ->orderby('dates','desc')
    ->select('research_papers.id','research_papers.title','research_papers.dates','research_papers.abstract','research_papers.paperlinks','authors.authors','keywords.keywords','research_papers.doi','favorite_models.researchpaper_id','research_papers.websites')
    ->paginate(10);

    return $researchpapers;
  }
```

I hope it would be helpful. It's working for me.

Comment: sir, i tried this type of join. but in this type of join. foreign key is not working because mongodb created obj primary key. so it doesn't match with the local key and foreign key.